# localsettings.properties : How to use its properties for JTest configuration?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, parasoft, jtest

I'm trying to learn about the Maven Parasoft plugin, for JTest.

Full name for version 3.12 : **Parasoft:maven-parasoft-plugin:3.12:jtest**

First, except Apache website, I didn't find any tutorial about this plugin. I Wonder if i'm using bad keywords in my Google research. So I would be so pleased if somebody helps me by some links.

Well, reading in the Apache website this doc :
http://build.parasoft.com/docs/maven-parasoft-plugin/jtest-mojo.html
 I try to imagine how the file **localsettings.properties** looks like.

In the table, I find the **localsettings parameter** and they say that it :

> reads the local setting file for global
>   preferences, such as Report Center, email, and Team Server settings
>   Default value is: ${project.basedir}/localsettings.properties.

This is interesting. But I can't see much how I can use the properties which exist in this file.

For example, let's suppose that I have in this file the following key-value :

```
my.company.parasoft.server.address=our.server.address.value
```

How can Parasoft understand that the key **my.company.parasoft.server.address** means the address of our company's parasoft server? I don't see any parameter (idem tag) to do something in **pom.xml** like this :

```
<concertoAddressTag>${my.company.parasoft.server.address}</concertoAddressTag>
```

... or by maven command line :

```
... -DconcertoAddressTag=%my.company.parasoft.server.address%
```

Or maybe that the keys should have an exact name to be recognized automatically??

**Note :** Any useful information about this plugin will be so appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localsettings.properties is Parasoft own format containing set of predefined key-value pairings, which enable configuring your local environment, setting up reporting options, task assignments, licensing details and more.

You can find a list of keys and values which can be recognized by the tool in Parasoft Jtest User's Guide.

Generally those options are supposed to be stored in a separate file either locally or on your Concerto server (more information [here](http://www.parasoft.com/development-testing-platform/alm)).

Still, if you'd like to extend list of options imported from Concerto in your pom.xml file, you can do it by explicitly entering key-value pairings, preceeded by additionalProprties tag decribed [here](http://build.parasoft.com/docs/maven-parasoft-plugin/localsettings-mojo.html#additionalProperties).

Please also take a note that there's not much you can do with Parasoft Jtest Maven plugin without having a licensed copy of the software itself set up locally or remotely (more information [here](http://www.parasoft.com/jtest)).